# How to active line item column in NetSuite Journal entry record

Tags: netsuite

I can get the line Item Column From [Official Field Browser](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/script/record/journalentry.html),

but it had not shown in our NetSuite application, Any idea how to active it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Journal Entry Record, and in the `EDIT MODE` hover over Customize at top right and select Customize Form.

Then you can navigate to `Screen Fields` subtab. In here you can further navigate to `Lines` section.

[image: Lines Section]

Here you can change select from different available options.

Let me know in case of any issues in comments below.

Comment: I had update my question for `customise form` >`Screen fields` >`lines`  settings, but I still cannot get the "Item" column, Any idea what to do next?